# Issue in loading HTML/JS files from appdata folder of windows 8.1 Cordova app

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-8.1, appdata

I am  developing `Cordova` App for `windows 8.1`. I have developed functionality which downloads zip from web and extracts it to "AppData (`appdata:///local/`)" folder of the application.

That zip file has HTML and JS files. Now I want to display that html in windows app. I am accessing a html file 'home.html' file as "`ms-appdata:///local/home.html`", but it is not accessible

Any kind of help/suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Same problem, did you find any response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not support accessing JS/HTML/CSS from AppData. To access JS/HTML/CSS from AppData (ms-appdata:///local/), insert a web view inside the index page as follows

```
<x-ms-webview id="id-web-view" height="100%" width="100%"></x-ms-webview>
```

and call navigateToLocalStreamURI to navigate the page.

Need to build a bridge to call into the cordova plugins in order to pass data back and forth from the content.